# How to save tensorflow 2 model with attention layer (NotImplementedError)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to save a tensorflow 2 model that contains an attention layer (tf.keras.layers.attention).

I've tried using model.save() and model.to_json(), both produce the following error:

NotImplementedError: Layers with arguments in `__init__` must override `get_config`.

There is no error when the attention layer is removed from the model.

I should clarify that I am using Keras in Tensorflow 2 to handle the sessions and model layers/compiling/training. I am able to save a trained keras model for a recurrent network without attention. However when I use keras.layers.Attention, the model can still compile and train, but will not save using the above commands.

Comment: Hi @Alex Golin, can you include a minimum reproducible code that can show your error?